# Install applications on android market through my computer

Tags: applications, google-play-store, web-market

My phone model is Xperia Neo.
My computer has an internet connection but my phone doesn't.
I followed following steps to install app to my mobile from computer

- Go the market app website.
- It shows my phone model and when I click on Install
- It shows the message that This application will be installed shortly
  but actually nothing happens.

I have seen following video also which shows how to install app from computer but It is not working for me.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=evAiHzNPEgw

Is there any problem with my phone or do I have to do something else?

Comment: After sending install signal from site, do a force sync on device. Open Gmail and press options to get sync option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Play store website works by sending a notification to your phone asking it to install the app. If you're having problems with that make sure that:

- Your phone has Internet connection
- You logged in with the same Google account that's on your phone.
- You're logged in to Google Talk on your device
- Background data is enabled
- Syncing is enabled for your main account's Gmail.

These are the most common reasons that can cause push notifications (this is the way Web install is handled ) to malfunction.

---

If your phone doesn't have Internet connection and want to install apps though by downloading them to your computer first you could try following [this](http://geniusgeeks.com/download-apk-from-google-play-pc/) tutorial.

However I would personally advise against it because it requires you to disable certificate error warnings and enter your password. If you want to do it at least create a second chrome profile for this and enable [2-step verification](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=180744)

Comment: I don't have internet connection on my phone that means I can't download app from market app website even if I have internet connection on my computer.

Comment: @HellBoy The market website only tells your phone to download the app, it does not download it.

Comment: @HellBoy added a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The way this works is that the online market desktop site sends a message to the market app on your phone to download and install the app.

If you open the market/google play app on your phone and leave it for a while, it should work.

Make sure your phone has an internet connection though.

Comment: so there is need of internet connection on my phone too if I don't have internet connection on my phone then I can't download app from my computer. Is it?

Comment: Correct, you need internet connection on your phone too.